# Create shape with a hole in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I create a shape with a hole in Excel VBA?

```
    Private Sub test_freeform()
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Set ws = ActiveSheet
      With ws.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, 20, 20) ' returns FreeFormBuilder
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 100, 20
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 100, 100
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 20, 100
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 20, 20
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 30, 30

        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 30, 60
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 60, 60
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 60, 30
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 30, 30

        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 20, 20
        .ConvertToShape
      End With
    End Sub
```

This creates the shape with a segment that connects top left corner of the outer rectangle with top left corner of the hole. I want to somehow get rid of that segment.
Some of the predefined Excel shapes have proper holes in them, so I know it is possible for such shape to exist.

Comment: What kind of shape are you trying? In Excel 2010, there are in built shapes with holes in them like `msoShapeDonut` and `msoShapeFrame`

Comment: Pankaj, Those are predefined shapes. I want to create my own shape programmaticaly, which has one or more holes in it. The shape is a rectangle and size and position of holes depends on a data I pass to routine.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you, it's kind of a workaround:

**Tested and Working on Excel 2003**

***Edited code: kept just the rectangle***

```
Private Sub test_freeform()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rectShp As Shape
    With ws.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, 20, 20) ' returns FreeFormBuilder
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 100, 20
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 100, 100
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 20, 100
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 20, 20

        Set rectShp = .ConvertToShape
    End With

    Dim bRed As Byte, bGreen As Byte, bBlue As Byte
    bRed = 255:  bGreen = 0: bBlue = 0

    Dim cirShp As Shape
    Set cirShp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 50, 40, 20, 20)

    With cirShp.Fill
        .Solid
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(bRed, bGreen, bBlue)
        Dim holeColor As Long
        holeColor = .ForeColor.RGB
    End With

    cirShp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = rectShp.Line.ForeColor.RGB

    Dim grouped As Shape
    Set grouped = ws.Shapes.Range(Array(rectShp.Name, cirShp.Name)).Group

    grouped.Copy
    Dim imgShp As Shape
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Image (GIF)"
    grouped.Delete
    Set imgShp = ws.Shapes(1)

    imgShp.PictureFormat.TransparencyColor = holeColor
    imgShp.PictureFormat.TransparentBackground = msoTrue

End Sub
```

**Edit: Picture added:**

Here is what it looks like on 2003, that's why I thought it was good enough ;)
[image]

Comment: Just tried it on Excel 2010 and it works better on 2003.  Maybe tweaking the color parameters could do the trick and maybe using Bitmap instead of GIF.

Comment: Thanks, it is an interesting trick. I tried it in Excel 2013 and it works there. I do not quite understand why it works. I would expect that part of original rectangle is seen through the transparent parts of the image, not the background.

Comment: @nsg; It is because it is pasted as a picture so the whole thing (rectangle + circle) are fused together and then you select the circle's filling color as transparent.

Comment: +1: The picture trick to force the transparency is very nice.